# Maths of chords

Tags: waves, acoustics, fourier-transform, frequency, superposition

The next question has been transmitted from the math stack exchange site as the math community suggested me to ask physicists:

I have a few naive questions on music theory. Let us assume that I have two pitches A and C with certain frequencies. Then the corresponding sound waves are pure sinusoidal waves. But what happens if I vibrate the chord A-C? To get the resulting wave, I should simply sum up mathematically the corresponding sin waves? Conversely, if someone gives me a wave, how can I say that is, for instance, an A-C chord?

I am looking for an oversimplified model to see the essentials of the theory.

Any remarks welcomed.

Comment: The oversimplified model would be Fourier analysis, which does exactly what you ask for: tells you which sine waves are in your signal. In reality however, automated chord recognition is not easy, as the kind of sounds we like do not consist of pure tones.

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2552093/11127

Comment: Yes, the waveform of a chord is just the sum of the waveforms of the individual notes.  CDCM mentioned Fourier Analysis.  Basically, _any_ periodic function can be expressed as a sum of sin() and cos() functions. 
 A [Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) is a computational tool that you can use to analyze a given wave form, and decompose it into that sum of sin() and cos() functions.

Comment: It is impossible to pluck a string in a pure sinusoidal wave. There will always be harmonics present. On http://www.falstad.com/loadedstring/ one can try to get the Java-applet running (difficult on today's operating systems) which shows an instructive interactive simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you suggest is essentially correct. If you have a standing wave (say, a vibrating piano string) vibrating at 440 Hz, you will create the note A (above middle C). You could write the displacement of the string by

$$y(x,t)=y_0 \cos(\omega t-kx)$$

where $x$ is the position of the string, $\omega=2\pi f$ (for frequency $f$) and $k=2\pi /\lambda$ is the wave number. This string will produce a sound equivalent to a single frequency tone $f$=440 Hz A. You also have the relationship $\lambda f=v$ for $v$ the speed of the wave on the string.

If you had a second string, vibrating at whatever the frequency of C is, you would have the same expression for the second string with the correct frequency of C.

The result at your ear (position $\vec{r}$) would be something like a pressure (sound) wave that obeys the principle of superposition,

$$P(\vec{r},t)=P_A \cos(\omega_A t +\vec{k}_A\cdot \vec{r})+P_C \cos(\omega_C t +\vec{k}_C\cdot \vec{r})$$

The slight complication here is the relationship bewteen $\lambda$ and $f$ will no longer be the speed on the string, but rather the speed of sound in air. But it's roughly equivalent - you can add the two waves together.

That's the simple, essentially correct, picture. The complication brought up by CDCM is very real, however - notes from musical instruments are never "pure tones". Even the vibrating strings of the piano produce higher harmonics (at the octave, 5th above that, 4th above that, etc etc etc). So in reality the pressure wave from your "single note A" looks more like

$$P(\vec{r},t)=\sum P_i\cos(\omega_i t-\vec{k}_i\cdot \vec{r})$$

for a set of frequencies $f_i$ that is highly dependent on the instrument used. That set of frequencies is not only why a guitar sounds different from a flute, but why 300 year old Italian string instruments are more valuable than the modern equivalents.

Comment: Off topic but why does this make old instruments more valuable? :D Never understood this. They sound different because of their age or is it a manufacturing technique we cannot reproduce these days (unlikely?!)?

Comment: I will only answer from my direct experience (playing the Double Bass). Wood dries out as it ages, improving the sound quality of instruments made from it. And the drying process doesn't happen in nature (or like, in common life like wood for a house) because these instruments have also been carefully preserved. So, they sound better because the wood is old and well-preserved.